# Grouping XML with Linq, Hierarchy isn't right

Tags: c#, xml, linq, treeview

I'm trying to work out how to create a treeview menu from a sql query in asp.net C#. As a learning exercise, I've got a database containing holidays from the past three years -- I want to create a treeview displaying the holidays sorted by year. For example, "Year --> Holiday Name --> Holiday Date", where "-->" denotes a hierarchical level.

Anyway, I'm getting my holidays returned as an XML doc from SQL using this query:

```
SELECT  [Year], [Holiday], [Date] FROM [Database] FOR XML PATH('Holiday'), ROOT('Holidays')
```

This, of course, returns an XML document with no grouping, so I'm using Linq to group my holidays by year while the data's coming from the database, like so:

```
XmlReader reader = sqlCommand.ExecuteXmlReader();

    if (reader.Read())
    {
        XElement doc = XElement.Load(reader);
        var newData =
            new XElement("Holidays",
                from data in doc.Elements("Holiday")
                group data by (int)data.Element("Year") into groupedData
                select new XElement("Group",
                    new XAttribute("ID", groupedData.Key),
                    from g in groupedData
                    select new XElement("Holiday",
                        g.Element("Name"),
                        g.Element("Date")
                    )
                )
            );
```

This is better: it groups my holidays by year, but my treeview ends up looking like this:

```
2012
    Holiday
        Christmas Eve
        12/24/12
    Holiday
        Christmas Day
        12/25/12
    Holiday
        New Year's Eve
        12/31/12
```

... and so on. I'm new to Linq, so I'm not really sure what to do here. I want to get rid of that "Holiday" level and make the actual date a child node of the Holiday name. I can't do anything with the SQL query, since XML can only have one root node. Any ideas?

Comment: You don't explain how your XML is displayed in your tree, but I infer from your code that if an element has an attribute `ID` then that will be displayed; otherwise `XElement.Value` will be displayed.  Is that correct?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since you tree apparently uses the `ID` attribute of an `XElement` as the tree node label, if such an attribute exists, you could add the holiday name as an ID attribute of the `Holiday` node, rather than as a nested attribute:

```
            if (reader.Read())
            {
                var doc = XElement.Load(reader);
                var newData =
                    new XElement("Holidays",
                        from data in doc.Elements("Holiday")
                        group data by (int)data.Element("Year") into groupedData
                        select new XElement("Group",
                            new XAttribute("ID", groupedData.Key),
                            from g in groupedData
                            select new XElement("Holiday", new XAttribute("ID", g.Element("Name").Value), g.Element("Date"))
                        )
                    );
                var newXml = newData.ToString();
                Debug.WriteLine(newXml);
            }
```

For the following input:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<Holidays>
    <Holiday>
        <Name>Christmas Eve</Name>
        <Date>12/24/12</Date>
        <Year>2012</Year>
    </Holiday>
    <Holiday>
        <Name>Christmas</Name>
        <Date>12/25/12</Date>
        <Year>2012</Year>
    </Holiday>
    <Holiday>
        <Name>New Year's Eve</Name>
        <Date>12/31/12</Date>
        <Year>2012</Year>
    </Holiday>
</Holidays>
```

This gives the following output:

```
<Holidays>
  <Group ID="2012">
    <Holiday ID="Christmas Eve">
      <Date>12/24/12</Date>
    </Holiday>
    <Holiday ID="Christmas">
      <Date>12/25/12</Date>
    </Holiday>
    <Holiday ID="New Year's Eve">
      <Date>12/31/12</Date>
    </Holiday>
  </Group>
</Holidays>
```

(Note you can't use the holiday name as an `XElement` name because some of the holiday names contain spaces.)

Comment: This produced the output I was looking for. Many thanks for your assistance.

Answer (score 0):

Change your select statement...

```
   select new XElement(
                            g.Element("Name").Value,
                            g.Element("Date")
                        )
```

Comment: Close, but that just makes the second and third levels of my treeview the date, ie, "2012 --> 12/24/12 --> 12/24/12". It should be "2012 --> Christmas Eve --> 12/24/12